# Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly” when trying to start Red5

Tags: red5

I get this error

```
Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly” when trying to start Red5
```

when I am trying to start red5 service I tried to reinstall red5 and the problem still apper, what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing java x32